# How to center a p element in the screen without a body or html element and create a black background

Tags: html, css, centering

What I want to do is to use `<p onclick='this.innerHTML++'>0</p>` and make this code have a black background that covers the whole screen and center the text in it. I want it to not have a body element or an html element as I just want the `<p>` element.

I tried using box-shadows and the transform property in the `style` attribute.

```html
<p onclick='this.innerHTML++' style='color: white; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; transform: translate(-50vw, -50vh); box-shadow: 50vw 50vh black;'>0</p>
```

That just displayed a quarter of the viewport a fourth of whiteness which meant the box-shadow wasn't working. I found it added a margin, so I removed it. It still didn't work. It centered the text though. I know how to do it with 2 elements, but I want to keep the code with only the `<p>` element.

This time I tried using the background property.

```html
<p onclick='this.innerHTML++' style='color: white; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background: black; text-align: center'>0</p>
```

This time the code did everything correctly except positioning the text vertically centered.

Is it possible to do this all in 1 element, center the text both horizontally and vertically, and display a black background that covers the whole screen?

Comment: You can easily get the text centered using `display:flex` and `justify-content` / `align-items`. You can not have a "naked" `p` element floating around in nothing though - even if you do not provide `html` and `body` in your code, the browser will automatically create them when building the DOM. And it will apply a default margin to body from the user stylesheet, usually 8px. So if you leave the p element in normal flow, you will have to compensate for that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center content you can either use flex or grid:

```css
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

or with grid, it's just two lines:

```css
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
```

I created a snippet for you. I changed your `<p>` tag to a button, since this would be more semantic valid HTML. You can of course use any element you like.

```css
button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="this.innerHTML++" type="button">0</button>
```

Comment: I wanted a `<p>` element without the use of the `<body>` element.

Comment: Wait, just without the body styles I meant to say.

Comment: You can't remove the `<body>` It will be always added by the browser, even if you don't add it. And it will always have the default styles added to it. If you then use a non semantic `<p>` or a semantic `<button>` element is up to you. Edited my snippet, you can achieve this with absolute positioning.

Comment: I know, it's just the source code without the `<body>` element.

Comment: updated the snippet to not use body-styling anymore.

Comment: oh, btw `inset: 0;` instead of `left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;`

Comment: I think I can settle with `<p onclick='this.innerHTML++' style='box-sizing: border-box; color: white; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background: black; display: grid; place-content: center; margin: 0; padding: 0; inset: 0; position: absolute;'>0</p>`

Comment: you are correct, `inset: 0` is much shorter and better in this case. :) I will leave it in the answer, so the comments down here make sense.